# Heartbeat (Linux HA) and NetApp?

Tags: linux, high-availability, netapp, heartbeat

Does anyone have any experience setting up a high availability two node Linux cluster using heartbeat (linux-ha.org) and NetApp storage (preferably using SnapDrive for Linux)?

Basically I would like to mount the same NetApp LUN over Fibre Channel to two servers in an Active/Passive mode (only one server can access the LUN at a time)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What's your question?  It's technically possible.

Unless there's a requirement otherwise, I would probably have the storage mounted in a resource script as opposed to keeping it mounted at all times.

Answer (score 1):

So as you have specified using a LUN via fibre channel, then you would also need to have a clustered file system. At that point is there a reason you are not using nfs ?

As warner says why would you want to do it ? I am pretty sure you could do it but you would treat as any other system. eg

- Create the lun
- Present the lun to the hosts
- Format clustered filesystem
- Mount on each host.

However what are you trying to do that needs a clustered file system rather than simple nfs ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a clustered file system for what you are trying to do (at least not on Linux). What you want to do is *mount* that file system from the LUN only once wich heartbeat/pacemaker should do just fine as your file system is a resource with defined ownership. Presenting a LUN to two hosts at the same time is generally not a problem (on Linux).